# Strange error regarding delegates when calling Array.Sort()

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, delegates

I have this method containing a call to `Array.Sort()` with a custom comparison delegate to sort them by closeness to a 3d vector;

```
GameObject[] GetGrabbableObjects(Vector3 SortedByClosestPoint)
{
    GameObject[] Grabbables = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Grabbable");
    Array.Sort(Grabbables, delegate (Vector3 A, Vector3 B) { return (SortedByClosestPoint - A).magnitude.CompareTo((SortedByClosestPoint - B).magnitude); });
}
```

Even though I'm fairly sure I composed the parameters properly, Visual Studio is giving me an error on the delegate, `Cannot convert anonymous method to type 'Array' because it is not a delegate type`, as though it's trying to use a different overload.

And yes, it's a unity script, but this seems more relevant to C# than Unity

Edit: Sorry guys, wrong datatype. Delegate should take two `GameObjects` instead of two `Vector3`s.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `delegate (GameObject A, GameObject B)` ?  The delegate parameter types should match the array type.

Comment: What should I do to fix it? I haven't really worked that much with delegates.

Comment: Oh. that was it, sstan